# Application of Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Tags: measure-theory, limits, integration

Find $L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{n a} \exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{1+\frac{b t}{n}}\right) dt$, where $a>0$, $b>0$.

I can't see what is dominating function, but I feel that I have to use Dominated convergence theorem. Any kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the integral as

$$\int_0^{n a} dt \: \exp\left(-\dfrac{t}{1+\frac{b t}{n}}\right) = n a \int_0^1 du \: \exp\left(-\dfrac{n a u}{1+a b u}\right)$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the contributions from the integral come mainly from the neighborhood near $u=0$.  In this limit, then

$$L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n a \int_0^{\infty} du \: e^{- n a u} = 1$$

Comment: i have a small q about your ans:
i to got to the point where the integral of u is between 0 and 1/
in the next step you take L to be the same integral but u is now from o to infinity.
why is that?
is that a mistake?
because my ans is 0... thanks!

Comment: We can set the upper limit to $\infty$ because the error in doing so is exponentially small as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  In fcat, you can see that in evaluating the integral with the finite limit.